# Erro em utilizar ViewBag no DropDownListFor ASP NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Tenho um DropDown que lista as categorias do meu sistema, mais quando submeto o formulário sem escolher uma categoria, ele da um erro de servidor dizendo que o Valor não pode ser nulo.
Coloquei uma validação com o ValidationMessageFor, mais mesmo assim não funciona e da erro. Se tirar meu DropDown ele valida os outros campos, inclusive um outro DropDown q tenho no mesmo formulário, mais que não utiliza ViewBag.
Se alguém puder me ajudar..

Segue Controller:

```
public ActionResult Adicionar()
    {
        var cookie = DinheiroControlado.Repositorios.RepositoriosUsuarios.VerificaSeOUsuarioEstaLogado();
        ViewBag.teste = cookie.IDUsuario;


        ViewBag.Categoriaslist = db.Categorias.ToList();

        var lista = new List<Categorias>();
        lista = db.Categorias.ToList();

        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Adicionar(Movimentacoes movimentacoes)
    {
        var cookie = DinheiroControlado.Repositorios.RepositoriosUsuarios.VerificaSeOUsuarioEstaLogado();

        movimentacoes.IDUsuario = cookie.IDUsuario;
        var contador = movimentacoes.Parcelas;
        if (contador > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < contador; i++)
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    if (i == 0)
                    {
                        db.Movimentacoes.Add(movimentacoes);
                        db.SaveChanges();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var data = movimentacoes.Data.Day + "/" + (movimentacoes.Data.Month + 1) + "/" + movimentacoes.Data.Year;
                        movimentacoes.Data = Convert.ToDateTime(data);
                        movimentacoes.Parcelas = movimentacoes.Parcelas - 1;
                        db.Movimentacoes.Add(movimentacoes);
                        db.SaveChanges();
                    }





                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Movimentacoes.Add(movimentacoes);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(movimentacoes);
        }





        return View(movimentacoes);
    }
```

Segue View:

```
@model DinheiroControlado.Models.Movimentacoes
@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Adicionar";
   Layout = "~/Views/Layout2.cshtml";
 }
 <section id="title" class="emerald">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <h1>Movimentações</h1>
                <p>Lance suas despesas e suas receitas de maneira fácil e rápida!</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <ul class="breadcrumb pull-right">
                    <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index","Home")">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="active">Movimentações</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section><!--/#title-->

<section>
  <div class="container">
     @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
     @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
     @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset class="registration-form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <legend>Movimentacoes</legend>
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.ReceitaDespesa, "DESPESA") Despesa<br />
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.ReceitaDespesa, "RECEITA") Receita<br />
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ReceitaDespesa)            
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Data, "", new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Data", @id = "datepicker"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Data)

        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Descricao, "", new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Descrição" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Descricao)
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Valor, "{0:C2}", new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Valor"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Valor)
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">

            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Parcelas, "", new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Parcelas", @type = "number", @mim = "0", @max = "400"  })

        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Mensal, new List<SelectListItem> { new SelectListItem { Value = "0" , Text = "SIM" }, new SelectListItem { Value = "1" , Text = "NÃO" } }, "Mensal", new { @class="form-control"} )

        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.IDCategoria, new SelectList(ViewBag.Categoriaslist, "IDCategoria", "SubCategoria"), "Categoria", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IDCategoria)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar" class="btn btn-primary"/>
        </p>
        <div>
            <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Movimentacao")"  class="btn btn-primary">Retornar</a> 

        </div>
    </fieldset>

    }
</div>
```

Segue Erro:

```
Erro de Servidor no Aplicativo '/'.
Valor não pode ser nulo.
Nome do parâmetro: items
Descrição: Ocorreu uma exceção sem tratamento durante a execução da atual solicitação da Web. Examine o rastreamento de pilha para obter mais informações sobre o erro e onde foi originado no código.

Detalhes da Exceção: System.ArgumentNullException: Valor não pode ser nulo.
Nome do parâmetro: items

Erro de Origem:


Linha 67:         
Linha 68:             <div class="form-group">
Linha 69:                 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.IDCategoria, new SelectList(ViewBag.Categoriaslist, "IDCategoria", "SubCategoria"), "Categoria", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control"})
Linha 70:                 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IDCategoria)
Linha 71:             </div>


Arquivo de Origem: c:\TCC\C#\DinheiroControlado\DinheiroControlado\Views\Movimentacao\Adicionar.cshtml    Linha: 69

Rastreamento de Pilha:


[ArgumentNullException: Valor não pode ser nulo.
Nome do parâmetro: items]
   System.Web.Mvc.MultiSelectList..ctor(IEnumerable items, String dataValueField, String dataTextField, IEnumerable selectedValues) +102
   CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Type , Object , String , String ) +155
   System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute4(CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3) +738
   CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Type , Object , String , String ) +309
   ASP._Page_Views_Movimentacao_Adicionar_cshtml.Execute() in c:\TCC\C#\DinheiroControlado\DinheiroControlado\Views\Movimentacao\Adicionar.cshtml:69
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +197
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +103
   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.RunPage() +17
   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +64
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +78
   System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +235
   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +107
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +291
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1a.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__17() +23
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +245
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19() +22
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +245
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19() +22
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +176
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20() +75
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +99
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +16
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +16
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +25
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +16
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9723757
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Comment: Pode ser que o modelState não esteja válido e com isso retorna pra view,  sem preencher a ViewBag.Categoriaslist de acordo com o seu código. Tente retornar ViewBag.Categoriaslist preenchida novamente se o ModelState não estiver válido.

Comment: Janderson, deu certo usar sua alternativa, resolveu meu problema cara, muito obrigado! Abraço.

Comment: Blz, coloquei como resposta ai você marca como certa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode ser que o modelState não esteja válido e com isso retorna pra view, sem preencher a **ViewBag.Categoriaslist** de acordo com o seu código. Tente retornar **ViewBag.Categoriaslist** preenchida novamente se o ModelState não estiver válido.